# Python subprocess command argument not recognized

Tags: python, shell

I'm writing a Python script to retrieve page counts from the SNMP-enabled printers on our network, and I'm wanting to use the SNMPWalk utility. For testing, I've placed the SNMPWalk executable in the system32 directory on my development machine, so I can call `snmpwalk` directly from the command line (which works just fine).

When I try to issue the same command through `subprocess` in Python:
`subprocess.call('snmpwalk')`, it tells me that `snmpwalk is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I haven't yet started adding any arguments, and I'm not using any operators, it's just a simple call to an executable on the system PATH that works in cmd but not from Python `subprocess`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it's an executable, try `'snmpwalk.exe'`

Comment: That gives the same results.

Comment: Did you run `snmpwalk` on cmd.exe using Administrator access?

Comment: Do you need to set subprocess to run an admin cmd.exe? I'm calling the Python script from an admin cmd.exe.

Comment: Solved the problem; apparently Python can't access any .exes inside system32. I moved the snmpwalk.exe to a different folder, and everything worked.